# Assigning a default value to a Microsoft Access Table Field?

Tags: ms-access

I have a database table in Microsoft Access. I want to assign the default value of one of those fields to another field that happens earlier in the same table.

I tried the value `=[Form1].[AssignedByes]` with no luck and the same for `=[AssignedByes]` but with no luck.

Can anyone help?

The field name I'm assigning the value to is `[RemainingByes]` and the field that assigning the value of is `[AssignedByes]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get around this problem, I create a Query that basically functions as the table.  I use it instead of the table when creating other queries, forms, etc.

I'm guessing that you copy [AssignedByes] into [RemainingByes], because [RemainingByes] will start off with the value of [AssignedByes], but you want to be able to change it later.

So, you can set up the Query with a calcualted field called [xRemaningByes]. You would enter the changed values in [RemainingByes].  Then set up a formulat in [xRemainingByes] that returns the value of [RemainingByes] if there is one, and it not, it returns the value of [AssignedByes].

[xRemainingByes]: Iif([IsNull([RemainingByes],[AssignedByes], [RemainingByes].

When you use the Query instead of the Table, you will use [xRemainingByes], which is the Query's calculated field, instead of the Table's field [RemainingByes].

---

ANOTHER OPTION ---
Create a field in the Table such as [RemainingByesOverride], and that would be where you hard enter the changing data.  Then get rid of [RemainingByes] in the table and only have it in the Query as a calculated field.

[xRemainingByes]: Iif([IsNull([RemainingByesOverride],[AssignedByes], [RemainingByesOverride]

Answer (score 1):

A field's default value is applied at the instant a new record is created.  So you can't use [AssignedByes] as the default value for [RemainingByes], because [AssignedByes] doesn't have a value yet.

OTOH, if you've assigned a default value property for [AssignedByes], use that same *property* for [RemainingByes].

If your Access version is 2010, see whether you can use a data macro as a pseudo-trigger to accomplish what you want.

You could also try binding a form to the table.  In the after update event of the control bound to [AssignedByes], you can assign a value to another control bound to [RemainingByes].  This could allow you to do what you need in the form, but won't apply for changes made outside the form.

Comment: Sigh, this is a rather bothersome limitation of default values.