# MS Access Set Default Value as [FirstName] & " " & [LastName]

Tags: ms-access, concatenation, default-value

Have a table with `FirstName` and `LastName` fields and I'd like to set the `Fullname` field to automatically fill with `[FirstName] & " " & [LastName]`. Can I do this using the Default Value property only or is it more complicated?

I have tried an expression using variations of:

```
=[FirstName] & " " & [LastName]
```

but I get errors saying the database engine does not recognise `[FirstName]`.

I am using Access 2007 if that is important.

Comment: check it https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0e6da585-42d9-4398-96b4-0a2339dc55c1/access-table-defualt-value-based-on-another-field-in-same-table?forum=accessdev

Comment: You won't get a specific answer without sharing specific examples of what data you're starting with, and what you want it to look like in the end. (Where is the data coming from and where is it going?)

Comment: Having a separate `Fullname` field in your table is a sure way into problems. [Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables.](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404785/5938182), I think it's not possible.

But on a form, there are some answers. A quick search shows [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692369/ms-access-setting-default-value-of-a-field-to-be-the-values-of-two-other-field). You can use text field property, macro or VBA definition.

Of course Doug Coats's comment works, but in newer versions of Access. That doesn't work on Access 2007, as needed by OP.

Hope that helps.